# How to show appropriate icon on dialog box

Tags: android, dialog, icons, alert

I have an application that allows the users to delete video files. When I press the delete button, I am using

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            // mycode........
            break;
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            // mycode.....
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

But this message doesn't have a warning or delete icon as we see in android devices. Can anyone help me in getting those icons or using any other alert dialogs that can show those icons?

Comment: please post the code, where you are creating AlertDialog.

Comment: Sir, I have used dialog (not alert dialog) and want an example of using alert diaglog.. can you give me one..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I tend to use AlertDialog.Builder like they show in the official doc example

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            MyActivity.this.finish();
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   })
   //Set your icon here
   .setTitle("Alert!")
   .setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
 alert.show();//showing the dialog
```

As for the actual icon look inside your sdk folder/platforms/android version #/data/res/drawable-mdpi or something

Comment: i tried to set drawable but it is not showing in the dialog box

Comment: hmm, try setting a title too. I think that might be why you're not seeing one. try my edited code.

Comment: Thanks alot sir. It worked.. Can you please tell me a bit more about other functions like putting the image in the center etc. Thanks once again

Comment: For that, you would have to create a custom dialog with your own predefined view.

Comment: @AlamKanak Your edit is just plain wrong... `setIcon()` is overloaded and accepts both `Drawable` instances as well as drawable resource ids!

Answer (score 9):

In order to set the default Dialog icons use:

```
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
```

There are a few more icons available:

- android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer
- android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info
- android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email
- android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);`
to
`.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));`
But it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Another (dirty) way:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon, typedValue, true);

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(typedValue.resourceId)
    ...
    .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set certain icon for the Alert dialog buttons as:

builder.setPositiveButtonIcon(  getResources().getDrawable( drawable.ic_menu_share  )

Answer (score 0):

just set the title for you AlertDialog. like this:

```
adb.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
```

ful example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
adb.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground);
adb.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
adb.show();
```